# MySQL query to concate all fields based on ID for facebook like notification

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get facebook notification style. And I am in confuse. How can I concate all the user who comments on same post.

My database is as follows:

### Notification table

```
 id | post_id | to_user_id  | from_user_id |   type      |      datetime      | type
 1     45      101              107          comment       2016-3-10 11:03:06   ads
 2     45      101              106          comment       2016-3-10 12:05:06   ads
 3     45      101              105          comment       2016-3-10 12:08:05   ads
 4     55      101              106          comment       2016-3-10 12:05:06   ads
 5     55      101              105          comment       2016-3-10 12:08:05   ads
```

### Register table

```
 id    |  name
 101      John
 105      Jack
 106      Anna
 107      Leo
```

### Post_ads table

```
 id |  title  
 45    Some text
 55    other text
```

Now I want to join 3 table `post_ads` from `post_id` and `register` from `from_user_id` and concate all user who comments in same `post_id` and if there are more than 2 user who comments on same post then I want display the count or number of user after 2 username.

I should be like:

```
 Leo, Anna and 1 other commented on post Some text.
 Anna, Jack commented on post Other text.
```

Above Leo, Anna and other username comes from register table and post like `some text, other text` comes from post_ads table

I could do join with all table and display the result with three rows but how can I make query for result like above. Is this possible with the mysql query. My query is as follows:

```
 SELECT * FROM notification INNER JOIN `register` ON `register`.id = `notification`.from_user_id INNER JOIN `post_ads` ON `post_ads`.id = `notification`.post_id WHERE `notification`.to_user_id = $userid"
```

Comment: Does the given table structure belong to `notification table`?

Comment: Yes, its notification table.

Comment: What do you want actually is not clear at all. Do you want `who commented  on a single post only` or `for every post who commented`? Please show your expected output and if possible along with given input data.

Comment: I have edited my question. It might be easy to understand now. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: You are welcome. Check the answer below. And if you need any explanation I can explain later. First ensure that the query is working in your case as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please first check that the query is working in your case. Later I can explain if required.

---

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
      substring_index(group_concat(finalTable.name SEPARATOR ','), ',', 2),
      IF((finalTable.total - 2) > 0,CONCAT(' and ',(finalTable.total - 2),' others'),''),
      CONCAT(' commented on post ',finalTable.title,'')
     ) AS output
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT n.post_id,
    n.from_user_id,
    post_ads.title,
    register.`name`,
    t.total
  FROM notification n
  INNER JOIN 
  ( 
    SELECT 
     post_id,
     COUNT(DISTINCT from_user_id) total
    FROM notification
    GROUP BY post_id ) t
  ON n.post_id = t.post_id
 INNER JOIN register ON register.id = n.from_user_id
 INNER JOIN post_ads ON post_ads.id = n.post_id
) finalTable
GROUP BY finalTable.post_id;
```

---

**Output:**

```
Leo,Anna and 1 others commented on post Some text
Anna,Jack commented on post Other text
```

---

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66f56/2/0)

Comment: It displays same username two times if same user comments two times.

Comment: How can I show username only onetime even if same user comments on same post two times.

Comment: Changed the query to do so.Please check now and let me know.@user254153

Comment: No, its not working now also and count of user is also not shown now.

Comment: Would you please check now. @user254153

Comment: Thank you, query is working now. But I am struggling on outputting other fields also instead of keeping all things in same string. Like array('users'=>'user1, user2 and 1 other', 'post_id' => '45', 'datetime' => '2016----', 'title' => 'some title')

Comment: I think it's a different task. I would suggest not to mix up different things in the same post. You may post your these requirements in another post. Better would it be! Thank you @user254153

Comment: Anyway I would try to make it myself. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: That's appreciated. And if you get stuck you may share with us with all relevant details. Happy Coding! :) @user254153

Comment: Hi, I need one help. I want to set read and unread status. read if 1 and unread if 0. So how can I set unread status if any of the rows with same post _id and from_user_id is 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106844/discussion-between-1000111-and-user254153).